# Complete list of ways you could die in Oregon Trail?

Tags: the-oregon-trail

Wikipedia gives the following (partial?) list:

> ...die from various causes, such as measles, snakebite, dysentery,
>   typhoid, cholera, and exhaustion. People could also die from drowning
>   or a broken leg.

But I'm pretty sure there were others (starvation for example).  Is there anywhere that has a complete list of the ways to dies in Oregon Trail?

Comment: Which version do you want to know about?

Comment: The first one, that was just titled "The Oregon Trail"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the text present on the disk images of the Apple II version, I believe this is the complete list:

- a fever
- dysentery
- measles
- cholera
- typhoid
- exhaustion
- a snakebite
- a broken leg
- a broken arm
- drowning

In particular, I couldn't find any indication that you could die of starvation.

Comment: According to wikipedia, you could also die from accidental gunshot wounds, so you might want to add that.  cheers =)

Comment: I find it very amusing that you could die from a broken arm, but you couldn't die from starvation =)

Comment: @Millard, my list comes from looking at the text present on the disks.  Neither the word "gunshot" nor the word "wound" appears anywhere.  Neither does the word "gun", and the word "shot" only appears in the context of reporting on the results of your hunting efforts.

Answer (score 1):

The 1978 BASIC source code https://github.com/LiquidFox1776/oregon-trail-1978-basic/blob/master/oregon-trail-1978.bas is not the original 1971 version, but it includes blizzard, snakebite, starvation, pneumonia, and injuries.